# Достаточно ли ориентироваться на хорошую адаптивность используя примеры в отладе Google Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте. Верстаю адаптивный сайт, но при сжимании окна браузера иногда всё выглядит не очень идеально (ничего не вылазит но не много есть косяки), но при этом все мобильные устройства и айпады в отладке Google Ghrome выглядят отлично. Достаточно ли этого, или надо чтобы все было идеально даже при обычном сжимании окна браузера?

Comment: Адаптивный, значит, и на уменьшение ширины окна должен реагировать корректно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В разных браузерах некоторые элементы имеют изначально немного разный стиль. Размеры, отступы... Для стандартизации можете подключить файл [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). Этот файл приводит базовые стили элементов к одинаковому виду во всех современных браузерах. После этого, можете верстать в любом браузере, только следите за поддержкой css свойств и тегов в поддерживаемых браузерах.

Что касается сжимания, вы сами определяете поведение страницы. Если вы решили что страница не может быть меньше определенных размеров, установите min-width, ведь ваша страница, какой бы адаптивной она не была, не сможет быть полезной если её сжать до 50 пикселей скажем. Поэтому если у кого-то будет такой специфический размер экрана - пусть такой человек прокручивает страницу.

Comment: я просто сделал например медиа запрос на 550(тип под моб устройства) а на 570 к примеру один блок там сьезжает немного. незнаю что делать. А случайно не подскажите на какие размеры именно надо бы делать медиа запросы?

Comment: Вы не учли длину полосы прокрутки (около 17 если это хром). Сделайте 570 вместо 550. Размеры выбирайте в зависимости от того на что вы верстаете. Если это адаптивный сайт, можете сделать больше 960, 960 и меньше, 600 и меньше, но установить min-width на 240 например